# Progress bar on filling up form

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I have a long form ..
What I want is that when the user keeps filling up the form .. On the right hand side , as he scrolls and fills , the bar must be advancing .

Please tell me how to do it !
Thanks in advance !
Picture :
http://fiitjoint.co.nf/untitles.html

Comment: read a tutorial about it, google it, or search the forums here for it. this isn't really suitable for stack overflow

Comment: Um Zeke .. I tried it , but failed so I opted for doing that via page1 page2 , so that in each page , i would have a picture that has the bar filled up ..

Comment: If you're asking people to do your work for you, forget it. But to point you in the right direction, this is something that would be done with javascript (no ajax or php required).

Comment: Joao , I'm just asking the concept . ( or say the correct way to it .. )

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very hard using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Add a `blur` event to each field and when they move on from each field, check to see if they have filled it out correctly.  If they have, advance the progress bar.

```
$("input").blur(function(){
    if(this.value!=="")
        // Advance the progress bar
});
```

See this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Yu55C/).